# Combine (merge/join/concat) two dataframes by mask (leave only first matches) in pandas [python]

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have `df1`:

```py
  match
0     a
1     a
2     b
```

And I have `df2`:

```py
  match  number
0     a       1
1     b       2
2     a       3
3     a       4
```

I want to combine these two dataframes so that only first matches remained, like this:

```py
  match_df1  match_df2  number
0         a          a       1
1         a          a       3
2         b          b       2
```

I've tried different combinations of inner `join`, `merge` and `pd.concat`, but nothing gave me anything close to the desired output. Is there any pythonic way to make it without any loops, just with pandas methods?

Update:

For now came up with this solution. Not sure if it's the most efficient. Your help would be appreciated!

```py
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='match').drop_duplicates('number')
for match, count in df1['match'].value_counts().iteritems():
    df = df.drop(index=df[df['match'] == match][count:].index)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can do with `groupby` and `cumcount` before `merge` ,Notice I do not keep two match columns since they are the same

```
df1['key'] = df1.groupby('match').cumcount()
df2['key'] = df2.groupby('match').cumcount()
out = df1.merge(df2)
Out[418]: 
  match  key  number
0     a    0       1
1     a    1       3
2     b    0       2
```

Comment: works great, thank you. One more detail, needed to add `on` parameter: `out = df1.merge(df2, on=('key', 'match'))`.